# How to deploy Cloud Functions with secrets from Secret Manager using Cloud Build?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-functions, google-cloud-build

I have a Cloud Function that I want deployed in my CD pipeline using Cloud Build. The function needs a couple of secrets stored in Secret Manager that I want to pull in as environment variables using the `--set-secrets` flag.

When I deploy manually with the CLI I have no issue:

```
gcloud beta functions deploy myfunction \
  --source src \
  --trigger-topic mytopic \
  --region europe-west1 \
  --runtime python39 \
  --set-secrets 'env_1=secret_1:latest','env_2=secret_2:latest'
```

However, when I try to deploy using Cloud Build with this configuration:

```
steps:
- name: 'gcr.io/cloud-builders/gcloud'
  args:
  - beta
  - functions
  - deploy
  - myfunction
  - --source=src
  - --trigger-topic=mytopic
  - --region=europe-west1
  - --runtime=python39
  - --set-secrets='env_1=secret_1:latest','env_2=secret_2:latest'
```

I get an error that the `--set-secrets` argument `must match the pattern 'SECRET:VERSION' or 'projects/{PROJECT}/secrets/{SECRET}:{VERSION}' or 'projects/{PROJECT}/secrets/{SECRET}/versions/{VERSION}' where VERSION is a number or the label 'latest'`. I don't understand why I get this error as I think my argument comforms to said pattern.

Is there something I am missing?

Comment: Can you try to remove the simple quote in your set-secret args?

Comment: Thank you, that was indeed the solution!

Comment: Did you know how to make this but for the firebase command?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

First, follow Guillaume's suggestion to remove the quotation marks  around each pair. Afterwards, it should look like this:

```
--set-secrets=env_1=secret_1:latest,env_2=secret_2:latest
```

Or alternatively, my suggestion is to enclose all your arguments as a list like the example below. I tested the config below and it worked on my end.

```
steps:
- name: 'gcr.io/google.com/cloudsdktool/cloud-sdk'
  args: ['gcloud', 'beta','functions', 'deploy', 'myfunction', '--region=europe-west1', '--source=src', '--trigger-topic=mytopic', '--runtime=python39', '--set-secrets=env_1=secret_1:latest,env_2=secret_2:latest']
```

> Note: Do not put spaces in --set-secrets value if you have multiple secrets

To learn more, check out this [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/build/docs/build-config-file-schema#args).

Comment: Thank you! Your first suggestion about removing the quotation marks did the trick :)

Answer (score 1):

Here is some documentation: https://cloud.google.com/build/docs/securing-builds/use-secrets

You need to use the secretEnv key as well as the availableSecrets declaration in your cloudbuild.yaml

Comment: Wrong answer ;)

Comment: Thanks for the input Cadet! I knew it was possible to bring a secret into a Cloud Function by first bringing it into Cloud Build and then interpolating it into an environment variable. However I was looking to have the Cloud Function refer directly to the secrets using the `--set-secrets` argument.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to Cadet's answer as this was what I needed, and I believe is best practice. https://cloud.google.com/build/docs/securing-builds/use-secrets
For those looking to utilise secrets manager, this is how to write your script

```
--set-secrets=app_user=projects/369177123123/secrets/app_user:1,app_pass=projects/369177123123/secrets/app_pass:1
```

Make sure that the secret names "app_user" and "app_pass" correspond with what you have named in your secrets manager.

Also, take note of the project number "369177123123" as it must match your own project number. You can get your project number by visiting your dashboard. or see this link https://cloud.google.com/resource-manager/docs/creating-managing-projects#identifying_projects

Lastly, make sure you give the service account access to the secrets. See https://cloud.google.com/build/docs/securing-builds/use-secrets#grant_permissions